# Link_to action in controller rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, link-to

I have this action in the controller families

```
 def hello
 end
```

With view hello.html.erb

```
 hello world
```

In the view of index in the same controller i have

```
<%= link_to 'hello',  families_hello_path %>
```

In my routes.erb i make this

```
post  'families/hello', to: 'families#hello'
```

but when un click on hello i have this error :

```
Couldn't find Family with 'id'=hello
```

where is the problem ?

Comment: can you add the output of `bundle exec rake routes |grep families` to your question?

Comment: you are looking for this ?

Comment: families_hello GET    /families/hello(.:format)                           families#hello

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't find Family with 'id'=hello

Definitely the request **isn't going** to `hello` method. As you declared the route as **post**, you should use `method: :post` in the `link_to` to send the request to `hello` method

```
<%= link_to 'hello', families_hello_path, method: :post %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here rails thinks that you have a route like /families/:id and you are doing a GET to the url of /families/hello. So rails thinks that you mean that 'hello' is the id of a Family record and goes to the `show` action.

If you go to your terminal and run `rake routes |grep families` you will see all of the routes you have configured for families and be able to adjust till you get the correct one. You should also take note of the http method which tells you POST for your current configuration in which case you have to use

```
<%= link_to "hello", families_hello_path, method: :post %>
```

but if you aren't changing data in your `:hello` action the right solution would be go change your method in your `config/routes.rb` file to read

```
get '/families/hello', to: 'families#hello' # Note changing 'post' to 'get' in the front.
```

Comment: if you are looking for a specific family record then your route should be "/families/:id/hello"

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to fix this:
The first one is to change the route.rb file

```
get 'families/hello', to: 'families#hello'
```

The second one is to change the view of index

```
<%= link_to 'hello',  families_hello_path, method: :post %>
```

I prefer the first option because it's more logical to set the method to a GET request to show a hello world page, but the two options still work.

Comment: Can you provide us with the whole route.rb file?

Comment: get 'welcome/index'
resources :purchases
resources :customers
resources :sales
resources :products
resources :users
root 'welcome#index'
post  'sales/add_produit', to: 'sales#add_produit'
post  'purchases/add_produit', to: 'purchases#add_produit'
get   'contacts/:id/del_role', to: 'contacts#del_role'
get 'families/hello', to: 'families#hello'
post  'contacts/add_role', to: 'contacts#add_role'
get   'sales/:id/delete_produit/:product_id' , to: 'sales#delete_produit'
get   'purchases/:id/delete_produit/:product_id', to: 'purchases#delete_produit'

Comment: I think I found your problem which is that you have something like `before_action :set_family` in your controller which will lead for this problem, if so you can fix it with `before_action :set_family, except: [:hello]`, I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i did it before, i did this and is work "<%= link_to 'hello', {action: 'hello'}, {method: :post} %>" but only if i click on hello...and if i want to click on hello and open another window i will have the same error !!! i think that the problem in the resources ??